# Angular 4: Argument of type 'typeof CLASS' is not assignable to parameter of type 'INTERFACE'

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I am playing around with dynamic components in angular.
But I have hit a problem I do not know how to solve.

I got this interface.

```
export interface InjectableComponent{
    setData(data: any): void;
}
```

Class implementing interface.

```
export class DemoComponent implements InjectableComponent {
    setData(data: any): void {

    }
}
```

Function using interface as argument type.

```
openComponent(component: InjectableComponent, data: any) {
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(<any>component);
    this.placeholder.clear();

    let componentRef = this.placeholder.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<InjectableComponent>componentRef.instance).setData(data);
}
```

Calling function.

```
openComponent(DemoComponent, null); <-- ERROR
```

Getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof DemoComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InjectableComponent'.
Property 'setData' is missing in type 'typeof DemoComponent'.
```

Can someone explain to me why this is not working? 
A workaround maybe?

Comment: You can try changing method `openComponent(component: Type<InjectableComponent>` https://plnkr.co/edit/bbejmaGKXVpgiRRBo3lE?p=preview

Comment: Thanks that worked. If you make an answer I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use special generic type `Type<T>` for that like

```
openComponent(component: Type<InjectableComponent>, data: any) {
   ...
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bbejmaGKXVpgiRRBo3lE?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `openComponent` method is expecting an instance:

```
   const demoComponent = new DemoComponent()

   ...

   openComponent(demoComponent, null);
```

Comment: I can see that, but I need the class type. It is used with .resolveComponentFactory.

I tried making the interface to an abstract class and then extending instead of implementing, but got a similar error.